# Must declare the table variable "@myTable"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE( 
Name VARCHAR(50), 
Year INT, 
Hours INT ) 

INSERT INTO @myTable *.... some values*

DECLARE @var INT 
SET @var = 2015

DECLARE @DynamicPivot VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @DynamicPivot = 'SELECT * FROM
@myTable  PIVOT( SUM(Hours) FOR Year IN (' + @var + ') ) AS PvtTable

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivot
```

I am trying to create a dynamic table and rotate the table using pivot. The value in @var is a value that already exists in the dynamic table `Year INT`. Everything works fine except when I try to execute the dynamic pivot. It gives me the error that `@myTable` is not declared even though I am running the whole code at the same time. The problem migh be in the pivot declaration by I don't really find the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the reason to use dynamics query? Where is @var from?

Comment: Variables declared outside the dynamic query are not available to the dynamic query. I don't see the need for a dynamic query here

Comment: Dynamic SQL executed with `sp_executesql` runs in a separate batch from the rest of your SQL.

Comment: I think it will work with a temporary table, but not a table variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `#` temp table and `sp_executesql` works only with `nvarchar`:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable ( 
    Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Year INT, 
    Hours INT
) 

INSERT INTO #myTable *.... some values*

DECLARE @var INT 
SET @var = 2015

DECLARE @DynamicPivot NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @DynamicPivot = '
SELECT * 
FROM #myTable
PIVOT( 
SUM(Hours) FOR Year IN ([' + CAST(@var as nvarchar(10)) + '])
) AS PvtTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivot

DROP TABLE #myTable
```

Comment: There is also no need for the quotes in the IN parentheses, since `YEAR` and `@var` are both `int`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Not sure about quotes, can not check this right now :)

Comment: Brackets are definitely not right, that would identify `@var` as an attribute.

Comment: Just checked - this will not work (if `@year` will be `int` and we put it as parameter in dynamic sql - it will bring errors `Error converting data type nvarchar to int.` and `The incorrect value "@year" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.`), I rollback the edits

Answer (score 5):

You should use the table variable inside the dynamic query..

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivot VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @DynamicPivot = '
DECLARE @myTable TABLE( 
Name VARCHAR(50), 
Year INT, 
Hours INT ) 

INSERT INTO @myTable *.... some values*

DECLARE @var INT 
SET @var = 2015

SELECT * FROM
@myTable  PIVOT( SUM(Hours) FOR Year IN (' + @var + ') ) AS PvtTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivot
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, Must declare the variables inside the Dynamic Query.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivot VARCHAR(MAX) 

DECLARE @var INT 
SET @var = 2015

SET @DynamicPivot = '
DECLARE @myTable TABLE( 
Name VARCHAR(50), 
Year INT, 
Hours INT ) 

INSERT INTO @myTable *.... some values*

SELECT * FROM
@myTable  PIVOT( SUM(Hours) FOR Year IN (' + @var + ') ) AS PvtTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivot
```

Comment: That answer helped me, worth remembering that when running in SSMS by F5 you need to select the whole operation (with Declare line also)